# Optimal way to install and keep Node.js & packages up-to-date on OS X?

Tags: node.js

What is the cleanest or most optimal way to keep an up-to-date installation of Node along with its accompanying packages on OS X?  Homebrew always seems a touch behind (except for `head`).

Additionally, an interesting observation from the [Node.js wiki says](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager):

> **Warning:** brew installs are known to be buggy

Further, is there a preferred method to update the installed packages as well (across node updates and just generally updating them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a tool called NVM to manage Node.js installation; you can install and switch to various versions of Node.js with a single command. You can find NVM at https://github.com/creationix/nvm.

You may be interested in the first half of [this screencast](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/2-nodejs-first-steps) that covers installing and using NVM (full disclosure: I made the screencast).

Comment: I as just about to ask about this a moment before your answer here.  I very much value `rvm` and this kind of functionality would be great.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I personally switched back to homebrew because installing the official package would foul up my path and which version of node I use.

And node packages shall not be installed globally so every new `npm install` will fetch the newest version if asked to do so.

Comment: Interestingly, what do you think of the edit I just made regarding the note on the Node wiki?  I'm quite curious after seeing that and it certainly discourages me even further from using `brew` now... :\

Comment: However, even seeing that, thinking a little more on this, one could easily update the formula for node in homebrew and actually just increment the version number from, for example, 0.8.5 to 0.8.6 even prior to the maintainer updating the formula.  Certainly see the advantages of running it via `brew`...